# Play2Torial + Play 2.0.3 + Heroku + Postgresql -- fails to build on push

Tags: java, scala, heroku, build, playframework-2.0

Working through James Ward's [Play2Tutorial](https://github.com/jamesward/play2torial/blob/master/JAVA.md), I made it to the final step, adding Postgresql database and pushing to Heroku.

I edited the Build.scala file per his recommendation:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    "com.github.twitter" % "bootstrap" % "2.0.2",
    "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"
  )
```

And modified my Procfile as well:

```
web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=$DATABASE_URL ${JAVA_OPTS}
```

The compiler is not returning any bugs on localhost, Heroku postgresql seems to be added fine, 
 but "git push heroku master" is failing at the last moment:

```
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_2;0.11.3 ...
   [info] Done updating.
   [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /tmp/build_3r8l8m531s747/.sbt_home/.sbt/plugins/target/scala-2.9.1/sbt-0.11.3/classes...
   [info] Loading project definition from /tmp/build_3r8l8m531s747/project
   [error] /tmp/build_3r8l8m531s747/project/Build.scala:12: ')' expected but string literal found.
   [error]         "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"
   [error]         ^
   [error] one error found
   [error] {file:/tmp/build_3r8l8m531s747/project/}default-f03173/compile:compile: Compilation failed
   Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?  !
Failed to build app with sbt!
Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Play 2.0 - java app

To git@heroku.com:********
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:********'
```

The code is a literal copy and paste, and I have had it working before (have worked through this tutorial without incident).

Would appreciate any advice you might be able to offer.

Thanks,
Chip

Comment: Looks like the separating comma of your dependencies in Build.scala file is not found on Heroku. Are you sure you have pushed the latest version of the `Build.scala` file to Heroku?

Comment: Glad you got this figured out.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the separating comma of your dependencies in Build.scala file is not found on Heroku. Are you sure you have pushed the latest version of the Build.scala file to Heroku?